# Cannot write to “HAIB_T47D_FoxA1.tar.gz” (Input/output error)

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, download, wget

I am trying to download a dataset (bigger than 1 GB) using wget:

```
wget http://cistrome.dfci.harvard.edu/MACSNatureProtocol/HAIB_T47D_FoxA1.tar.gz
```

However, I always get the following error message:

```
Cannot write to “HAIB_T47D_FoxA1.tar.gz” (Input/output error).
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission of destination folder and free space.